# Creating links on a web page that tell a mobile device to play the media such as mp4 rather than download it. (android / iphone)

Tags: iphone, android, html, mobile, webkit

Is there a way to specifically format a link on my page to tell a mobile device such as an Android phone or an iPhone that when a user clicks a link to a mp4 file (for example) to go ahead and play it (or ask the user if they want to play it) using their phone media player?

I'm working on a web app with mixed results, most of the times the device just goes straight into download mode, and attempts to save the file to the downloads folder, but what I would like is to make it so the device starts automatically playing the file as soon as possible.

My app is basically a file sharing app that creates qr codes and thus allows you to share media to mobile devices... the thing is, when it comes to video files and maybe images, I want the phone to automatically display the media and not just download it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can see the app here http://scan2see.me

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `<video>` tag to make your videos play instead of just linking to them.

Comment: Yeah I tried using the video tag, it works on desktop browsers but on android it just shows a placeholder with with a movie logo. Then the user has to press the super tiny little play button on the controller to get the video to play, and only plays at fulls screen (which is what I want but I want it to be automatically.)

Comment: Did you add an `autoplay` attribute?

Comment: Yes I used autoplay too with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

FYI iOS devices never download anything, unless jailbroken and with Safari Download Manager plugin (or other one like it) installed. So even if you just link, it will always play. And the reason why all videos play at full screen is because the iOS instantiate Quicktime to play it.